# Calculate the average date every x rows

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Previously I posted a question to calculate the average value for every 10 rows. It was successful in Zero's coding.
[Calculating the average value for every 10 cells in each column by pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72298713/calculating-the-average-value-for-every-10-cells-in-each-column-by-pandas)

However, there is an error in calculating the average value of the time date

```
import numpy as np

location2='C:\\Users\\Poon\\Downloads\\20211014_SBS_BEMS\\20211014_SBS_BEMS\\Test1044.csv'
csvfiles2=glob.glob(location2)

df3=pd.DataFrame()

for file_new_2 in csvfiles2: 
    df3=pd.read_csv(file_new_2)

    df4=pd.concat([pd.to_datetime(df3.iloc[:,0]), df3.iloc[:, 1:].apply(pd.to_numeric)], axis = 1)
    df4.dropna(inplace = True)
    df4= df4.groupby(np.arange(len(df4))//10).mean()

print(df4)
```

The error code is

```
Unable to parse string "2019-05-19 00:00:00" at position 0
```

I guess the commend pd.to_datetime cannot be summed up then divided by 10?

Here are some of the data from my excel, but totally there are 100k rows.

```
19/5/2019 0:00  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:01  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:02  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:03  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:04  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:05  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:06  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:07  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:08  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:09  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:10  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:11  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:12  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:13  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:14  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:15  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:16  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:17  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:18  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:19  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:20  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:21  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:22  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:23  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:24  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:25  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:26  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
19/5/2019 0:27  8840    20  237 64.93   82.35   16.15   46.88
```

Comment: You need to convert datetimes to timestamps first, then calculate averages and convert back to datetime. That's how I'd do this.

Comment: Can you share some sample data?

Comment: Added, please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming column `0` in the provided example, convert the timestamps to integer, group by the floor division of the index by 10 and aggregate:

```
import numpy as np
out = pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime(df[0])
                       .astype(np.int64)
                       .groupby(df.index//10)
                       .mean())
```

Output:

```
0   2019-05-19 00:04:30
1   2019-05-19 00:14:30
2   2019-05-19 00:23:30
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `resample`:

```
>>> (df4.assign(**{'dt': pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, 0])})[1:]
        .resample('10T', on='dt').mean())

                          1     2      4      5      6
dt                                                    
2019-05-19 00:00:00  8840.0  20.0  82.35  16.15  46.88
2019-05-19 00:10:00  8840.0  20.0  82.35  16.15  46.88
2019-05-19 00:20:00  8840.0  20.0  82.35  16.15  46.88
```

It can be easier if your columns have names.